# What is the equivalent operation of "clean" and "clean tomcat work directory" on Intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

On eclipse we can use clean and clean tomcat work directory on tomcat server to clear the cache and the app. What is the equivalent operation on Intellij? Do I need to manually delete those file in the /Users//Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea{.}/tomcat/ ?

Comment: @Leo Thanks, it's helpful. Does the following directory , /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea{<year>.<version>}/tomcat/
includes just the tomcat app? What if I would like to also clean the tomcat work directory as well?

Comment: Does invalidating cache also clean the tomcat work directory as well?